# Динамический массив выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++, память, динамические-массивы

[image: Само окно с ошибкой.]

````
    Код:
    Source.cpp
    ``` #include <iostream>
    #include "mass.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int g = 0;
        while (g<5||g>20) {
            cin >> g;
        }
        mass q(g);
        q.callmass();
    } ```



    mass.cpp
    ``` #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "mass.h"

    using namespace std;

    void mass::callmass()
    {
        for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << arr2[i];
        }
        delete [] arr2;
    } ```


    mass.h
    ``` #ifndef MASS_H
    #define MASS_H

    class mass
    {
    public:
        int* arr2 = new int[N];
        int N = 0;
        mass(int Q)
        {
            N = Q;
            int* arr1 = new int[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                arr1[i] = i * i;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                arr2[i] = arr1[i];
            }
            delete [] arr1;
        };
        void callmass();
    };
    #endif ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Для инициализации поля `int* arr2 = new int[N];` будет использовано неинициализированное значение `N`.

Comment: Если поменять эти строки местами ошибка сохраняется. Сам код выполняется корректно но после завершения вылезает это окно.

Comment: @AlexSNAKE ну если поменять эту строчку с `int N = 0;`, то поле будет инициализироваться указателем на массив из 0 элементов...

Comment: И как тогда правильнее поступить?

Comment: @AlexSNAKE Выделять память после того, как будет известен нужный размер, `N = Q;`. А еще почитайте про список инициализации. А еще `arr1` в этом примере не нужен

Comment: Разработать объект, который обладает следующей функциональностью:
- В конструкторе вводит количество элементов целочисленного массива.
- В конструкторе создает целочисленный массив заданным количеством элементов.
- Конструкторе определяет значения элементов массива. Значение каждого элемента равно квадрату индекса элемента.
- Выводит значения элементов массива в обратном порядке.

 Тут такое условие поэтому мне надо перенести значения arr1 массива в файл mass.cpp вывести их и отчистить помять выделенную под него

Comment: @AlexSNAKE Нет, в этом условии нигде не говорится про обязательное создание временного массива и переносе значений из него.

Comment: Необходимые свойства объекта определяется разработчиком.
Количество элементов массива принадлежит интервалу от 5 до 20. 

Написать программу:
1. Создает объект посредством оператора new.
2. Выводит значения элементов массива в обратном порядке.
3. Удаляет объект посредством оператора delete.
Входные данные
Первая строка (количество элементов массива): 
целое число в десятичном формате
Выходные данные
Первая строка, с первой позиции:
целочисленные значения элементов массива в десятеричном формате, каждое значение занимает 5 позиций (тут просто развернуто)